# Diff. b/w 2 ways of Getting instance for Connectivity Manager

Tags: java, android

What is the diffrence between these 2 statments:-

1)

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemServic(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

2)

```
Class  connectivityClass = Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
```

As, i can interpret both are giving me the instance of ConnectivityManager Class.

Answer (score 1):

In the second method you are using reflection to create an object of the class ConnectivityManager which comes with a price of Performance Overhead. So In particular it is recommended to avoid reflection if you can, as from the first method you can create an object of ConnectivityManager without reflection.

Some JVMs might not even allow you to create an object by reflection because of Security. Also it will make your life much more difficult in using objects created
through reflection

For more details on reflection look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html